# how to create links with database data in javascript

Tags: javascript, database

Actually i want create links with database single column data

Ex: Database

```
s.no---Categories---Category Description
-----------------------------------------
1      Games         cricket,chess
2      Books         Fiction,non-Fiction
-----------------------------------------
```

now i need to get category's names as links in my web application

Help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create a link you have to create another page for it , example

You create viewPage.php then in creating a link should be

```
<a link ="viewPage.php">Go to this link </a>
```

and if you want to pass variable through link just do it like  this

```
<a link="viewPage.php?categoriId=<?php $row["s.no"]?>" id="<?php $row["s.no"]?>">Go to this link </a>
```

if that is javascript i recommend you use jquery

Just create an event like this

```
<a link="viewPage.php?categoriId=<?php $row["s.no"]?>" id="<?php $row["s.no"]?>">Go to this link </a>

$("a").click(function(){
     window.location.href = "viewPage.php?"+$(this).attr("id");
});
```